# Linq include children from collection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, include, linq-to-entities

Using the include method does not include the children of a collection.

```
var abuseCaseQuery =
  from @event in 
    context.AbuseEvents.Include("AbuseCase.AbuseCaseStatus.Status")
  select new
  {
    @event.SecurityGroupId,
    @event.AbuseCaseId,
    @event.AbuseCase.AbuseCaseStatus
  }
;

var abuseCases = abuseCaseQuery.ToList();
```

The `abuseCases` List contains all the `AbuseCasesStatus` and the `StatusId` but the `Status` object is null.

edmx:

[image: edmx]

How can I populate the `Status` navigation property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF, `Includes` are ignored when you add a projection with `Select`.

So, you have to explicitly select all the data you want:

```
select new
{
  @event.SecurityGroupId,
  @event.AbuseCaseId,
  @event.AbuseCase.AbuseCaseStatuses
    .Select( acs => new { AbuseCaseStatus = acs, Status = acs.Status } )
}
```

---

This does result in a "flat" object, so you might like to fix up the object graph afterwards:

```
foreach( var abuseCase in abuseCases )
{
  foreach( var acs in abuseCase.AbuseCaseStatuses )
  {
    acs.AbuseCaseStatus.Status = acs.Status;
  }
}
```

Comment: I was unable to select the collection @event.AbuseCase.AbuseCaseStatus.Status. I am trying to use the select many function but having trouble with it.

Comment: The `AbuseCaseStatus` table has a `StatusId` column, so its `Status` navigation property should be a single `Status` object - is this not the case?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. Yes an `AbuseCaseStatus` object has one `Status` but in my select, `@event.AbuseCase.AbuseCaseStatus` is a collection of all the `AbuseCaseStatus` for that `AbuseCase`

Comment: My fault - I didn't look at your model closely enough. I've updated my answer.